# Call ajax function from <a> tag inside php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to call an ajax call from a list of elements in php. Well, this is a php code: 
http://pastebin.com/apf6gtq6

When i generate this list, i want click on the links and send the link to ajax call to perform the request. This is ajax call:
http://pastebin.com/mr8NmAy2

But When i click on a link i have got an error of this type:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Expected ')' to end a argument list.
```

I have searched the error but i can't find it. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: Firstly you should strip tags on the server side because you can do this for each request...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your onclick for the else part with this :-

```
<a onclick='javascript: theCall(" . $flight[$i] . ");'>$i</a>
```

Comment: i have tried replacing my instruction but i have the same error.

Comment: I have solved: i converted my php function in javascript function. Here's the code https://jsfiddle.net/meg1g5h0/

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line with this:

```
<a onclick=\"theCall(".$flight[$i].")\">".$i."</a>
```